# Contraction in present perfect

Tags: informal-language, contractions

I'm a bit confused when I use the contracted form of present perfect.

Do you write like this?

> My house's just been built.

Or you write like this:

> My house has just been built.

Which one is correct? Are there any rules for this?

Comment: I think both are correct, but I'd say, "My house has just been built." To my ear it sounds better.  I think that is because of the word 'has' -- and all the 's' sounds. My house's value is $123456, works.

Comment: @Willow Sound doesn't come into this... the question is about written English.

Comment: It all depends where the sentence is going to be used. See this post about the [use of contractions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/82937/2818). If in formal writing do not use contractions. When speaking or informal writing contractions are OK.

Comment: @Catija Actually sound most definitely *does* come into this. A contraction of *has* or *is* involves the loss of a syllable. However, there is no loss of a syllable in the OP's example because of the /s/ sound at the end of the original noun. For this reason the first example does not work well. It's not possible to cliticise the /z/ onto the noun base ending in /s/.

Comment: @Willow You might find my comment to Catija above useful/interesting.

Comment: @AraucariaMan The question specifically says "write"... people say many things that they do not write.

Comment: @Catija Yeah, but the writing has to follow the rules of the sounds. That's why we write *a university* and not *an university* and *an hour* and not *a hour* and so on.

Comment: @AraucariaMan I don't think that one example means it's always the case.  By your explanation no one would ever write "house's" because it's impossible to say.... which I disagree wholeheartedly with in the first place... but it is written all over the place.

Comment: @Catija Wel "house's"is fine anyhow for possessives, which are completely different. But you won't get 'house's' in printed books very often, in the same way that you won't see "the horse's been ..." - I don't think.

Comment: I would agree with Catija. You could write it both ways, but to me, using "has" is more immediately clear than contracting in this case.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang You cannot contract those. Contractions are a mirror of the sound involved. There is no contracted sound to mirror there.

Comment: To the OP: I see Araucaria Man's comment and I agree...academically, but this doesn't stop people from doing [this in real life](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=house%27s+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chouse%20%27s%20been%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is another reason to do so (such as clues from the discourse within which your sentence is part of), a reader will interpret the sentence to have been written in standard English (SE). And in SE, both ways of writing the present perfect are acceptable. However in formal writing, you may wish to stick to not using contractions, especially when indicating the present perfect. On the other hand,  in informal English the contracted form might  be the most natural way to express the present perfect and so it might be the expected form–especially if the intention is to represent or mimic spoken English.

Comment: In my (British) speech  "house has" has a different vowel (/ə/) from possessive "house's" (/ɪ/), so I would never write "house's" for "house has", even though in normal speech I would not pronounce the 'h' of 'has'.. But this is an oddity of words ending with /s/ and a couple of other sibilants. I would happily write "His car's just been fixed", because I pronounce the word identially with "cars" and "car's" (possessive). .

Comment: @ColinFine I think the issue is that you cannot cliticise a *has* or *is* onto a base ending in a sibilant. You can't just stick a /z/ on there. So because there's no loss of a syllable, *house's* won't work.

Comment: @AraucariaMan: I'm not sure if I agree. In my dialect, "The house is sold" and "The house's sold" would sound identical, and I think it's only convention that you don't write the second.